# Process characters from a txt file with line command as argument

Tags: c#, console-application

I tried to calculate the number of all lines and characters, vowels and constants from a txt file but I have this issue. When I try to run the program any advice on how should I resolve this issue because I tried to switch the method to a static but it didn't help at all here is the class which calculates the number of lines, vowels, consonants, and all characters

```
public class Continut
    {
        static bool IsLetter(char c)
        {
            return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
        }
        string fileName;
        int nrlines = 0;
        int nrvvowles = 0;
        int nrtotalcharacters = 0;
        int nrconsonant = 0;
        string vocale = "aeiouAeiou";
        public Continut  (string fileName)
        {
            fileName = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public void FindFileAndWork(string fileName)
        {                 
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
                    string line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        nrlines++;
                        nrtotalcharacters = nrtotalcharacters + line.Length;
                        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (IsLetter(line[i]) == true)
                            {
                                if (vocale.IndexOf(line[i]) != -1)
                                {
                                 nrvvowles++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                 nrconsonant++;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Folder dosen't exists");
                }
            
        }
       

    }
```

Here is the main code

```
 internal class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = Console.ReadLine();
            Continut.FindFileAndWork(filePath);
        }        
            

            
        
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more information on what problem it is you're having?

Comment: so it  gives me this error CS0120 at this line of code from the main fuction Continut.FindFileAndWork(filePath);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Continut.FindFileAndWork(filePath);
```

is trying to call a static mrethod, but it is not static

so do

```
 var ct = new Continut();
 ct.FindFileAndWork(filePath);
```

you will need an empty constructor too

```
    public Continut  ()
    {
        
    }
```